# Accessing local map data with AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, dictionary, gis

I'm creating an app with AppEngine (Java) that needs access to local map information.
In general, I'd like to search any query such as: gas stations, cheap restaurants, banks, or whatever in a certain area.

What is the best way to do this, and with which Service or API ?

Comment: This isn't really specific to App Engine.

Comment: I thought that because AppEngine is based on Google's infrastructure, that could be an easier way to access map data such as the Google Maps Data API.

Comment: Google App Engine is basically a Servlet Engine in the cloud. Google maps Data API is a client side API. They do not converge.

Answer (score 1):

This would be more of a Google Maps question than an appengine request (as mentioned in other comments).

That said, I would guess you are looking for an API or service something like Yahoo's GeoPlanet: http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/